# "Permission denied" when deleting files inside of .git folders

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm getting an error in my self-hosted github runners:

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/user/github-actions/1/_work/project/project/.git/index': Permission denied
```

It's not just this one file, but all the files that it tries to delete.

If I run something like: `sudo chmod -R 777 .` in the home directory, it will temporarily fix it. But the issue will come back. What can I do to fix this permenantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your runner fails with this error, double-check the output of:

```bash
ls -alrth /home/user/github-actions/1/_work/project/project/.git/index
ps -eaf|grep -i runner
```

That way, you can see:

- who has created that file
- what user is executing the current runner process

That allows you to confirm a user process issue (one executing the runner, the other the files).

> I wonder if Git is running as a separate user or something

No, it should not.

Comment: Result: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 437K Jan 11 20:04` - The account that i'm running on is not root. Why would git be using `root`?

Comment: @spierce7 It depends on the Github Action used: a container image might runs with an internal default user (inside the container) root.

Comment: yup that's what is happening. I guess I need to run my github action runners as root as a work around.